# Defining multiple VBA objects within one function or sub-routine?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA code:

```
Option Explicit

Private a(2) as Double
Private b(2) as Double

Public Function Hello(X1 As Double, X2 As Double) As Double

    a(1) = X1 + X2
    a(2) = X1/X2
    b(1) = X1
    b(2) = X2^2

Hello = a(1)+a(2)+b(1)+b(2)

End Function
```

Within the function `Hello` I have defined `a(1)`,`a(2)`,`b(1)`,`b(2)`.

However, I want to make some function or sub-routine that accepts `X1` and `X2` as arguments and spits out the values for `a(1)`,`a(2)`,`b(1)`,`b(2)`. This is because I use the above definitions for `a(1)`,`a(2)`,`b(1)`,`b(2)` in about 20 functions in my module and would like to avoid having to do the following in each function that I use thesis in:

```
    a(1) = X1 + X2
    a(2) = X1/X2
    b(1) = X1
    b(2) = X2^2
```

Comment: @MitchWheat I want some function or sub-routine that defines `a(1)`,`a(2)`,`b(1)`,`b(2)` as stated above that I can call within the 20 functions that need those definitions. As far as functions go I only know how to make them output 1 value, I don't know how to get them to define multiple objects.

Comment: @Harokitty: Even I am confused as to what exactly do you want? `I want some function or sub-routine that defines a(1),a(2),b(1),b(2) as stated above` You are not defining but assigning in the above code... There is a difference between the two.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Ok. Right now I have 20 functions. In each function I type those 4 lines where I assign values to a(1), a(2), b(1), b(2).    I want some way so I don't have to type those 4 lines in my 20 functions.  Note that in each of these 20 functions, the values of `X1` and `X2` are different so I can't just assign values to them outside of all 20 functions.

Comment: You don't need 20 functions if all you are doing is assigning values to `a(1),a(2),b(1),b(2)` You can simply use 1 function and then using conditional code, assign values to them.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I have 20 functions that do all sorts of stuff in my gigantic VBA project that I'm currently working on. The only thing that these 20 functions have in common is that they need `a(1),a(2),b(1),b(2)` to be assigned values contingent upon the `X1` and `X2` values that are unique to that specific function's argument list. I don't want to type 4 lines of code in all 20 functions to assign `a(1),a(2),b(1),b(2)` values, though. `""You can simply use 1 function and then using conditional code, assign values to them""` I don't understand this.

Comment: If it is just assigning values then you don't need a function. Posting an answer.

Comment: I would create a class object that holds `a()` and `b()` and act upon them with the methods in the class. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would structure this with a class object and properties/methods. Try this in `Class1`

```
Option Explicit

Private a(2) As Double, b(2) As Double

Public Sub Initialize(ByVal x1 As Double, ByVal x2 As Double)
    a(1) = x1 + x2
    a(2) = x1 / x2
    b(1) = x1
    b(2) = x2 ^ 2
End Sub

Public Property Get Hello() As Double
    Hello = a(1) + a(2) + b(1) + b(2)
End Property

Public Property Get Goodbye() As Double
    Goodbye = a(1) - a(2) + b(1) - b(2)
End Property

Public Function BusyWork(ByVal t As Double) As Double
    Dim i As Integer, x As Double
    x = 0#
    For i = 1 To 2
        x = x + (a(i) - t) * (b(i) - t)
    Next i
    BusyWork = Sqr(x)
End Function
```

And then use it in a module as

```
Public Sub UseClass()
    Dim c As New Class1

    c.Initialize 10.6, -4#

    Debug.Print c.Hello
    Debug.Print c.Goodbye
    Debug.Print c.BusyWork(-1#)
End Sub
```

You can read more about VBA classes here:

- http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If it is just assigning values to the array from different function then you can create a common procedure and call them from all the functions. See this example

```
Option Explicit

Dim a(2) As Double, b(2) As Double
Dim Hello As Double

Function FOne()
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '      
    Sample 1,2
End Function

Function FTwo()
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '      
    Sample 2,3
End Function   
'
'~~> Rest of the functions
'   
Function FTwenty()
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '     
    Sample 3.2 ,4.2
End Function

Sub Sample(X1 As Double, X2 As Double)
    a(1) = X1 + X2: a(2) = X1 / X2
    b(1) = X1: b(2) = X2 ^ 2

    Hello = a(1) + a(2) + b(1) + b(2)
End Sub
```